# Use F# option type in mvc ModelBinding?

Tags: f#, asp.net-core-mvc

is there a way for an mvc model to have a property that is of f# option type and have it bind to the model during Post (just like the nullable properties currently map, but instead of null/value it would be F#'s Some and None)?

Sample f# model:

```
[<CLIMutableAttribute>]
type Student = { StudentId : int; MainSportsId : int option}
```

Then in the controller post method:

```
[<HttpPost>]
member this.AddRecord(resp: Student) =
    resp.MainSportsId
```

Where resp.MainSportsId would be "Some number" if the user entered a number in the textbox or "None" if the textbox was empty.

Thank you!

Comment: Just out of curiosity - why you want to do that ?

Comment: Well, you could make yourself a custom binder...

Comment: @DimitarTsonev : I wanted to have an optional field in my form. In C#, I would make that property in the model a nullable int and it would work with MVC. But now that I am using F# to create the model, I wanted to use the Option as that is what seems to be the recommended approach for optional values. But I am open to suggestions as to the proper way to handle optional integers coming from a form post.

Comment: @FyodorSoikin I was looking at the docs in the official site and also MVC's code for their own binder, but it sounded like it was going to be very complicated given the generic parametric nature of the Option type (unless of course, I write a binder specific for the parent object, i.e the Student type). But beyond that, I thought this surely was a problem somebody had to have before, and thus had a solution a long time ago.